# How create a SP Calculated column based on date comparison

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column-formula

I am trying to create a calculated column based on a date comparison. This should be a simple if else block condition but its driving me nuts. I have a date column called "Expiration Date" and I am trying to add a calculated column as follows: If the Expiration date value matches today's date then calculated column value will be "Expired" else "Valid".

Can someone please help me out with the formula,thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The calculated column formula as below.

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Expiration Date]), "", If([Expiration Date]<=Now()+1,"Expired","Valid"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, one issue I am seeing is, in a scenario when Expiration date column is null then also calculated field shows value as Expired, in theory if expiration date is null then calculated column should also be left blank. Can you help?

Comment: I modify the reply above, check it.